# Why is nginx redirect not working with Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, http-redirect

I want to redirect a user when they go to https to the http version of my website which is hosted in a Docker swarm.

I'm trying to do this using ngnix, however the setup that I'm using isn't working.  I've created a new Core 2.0 Web App to try and get it working in the simplest context possible.  In addition to the Web App I also have my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build nginx image to redirect http to https
FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RedirectService.dll"]
```

and my nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://www.google.co.uk;
}
```

After building my image, I run it with `docker run -p 8006:80 redirectservice`.  What I'm expecting to happen is that it will redirect me to Google when I navigate to `http://localhost:8006`, however no redirect happens.

Can anyone see anything that I'm doing wrong?  Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Try:
docker run -it  - -net=host redirectservice /bin/bash
Then, try with curl to access google.com.
Or, try to locate nginx logs, and see what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not redirecting you, because nginx process is not running.
Take a look at the nginx image Dockerfile (https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/590f9ba27d6d11da346440682891bee6694245f5/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile) - last line is:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In your Dockerfile you replaced it with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RedirectService.dll"]
```

And thus the nginx is never started.

You need to create a sh script where you will run nginx and dotnet and wait until both of them ends (i.e. crashes).

Comment: Thanks for this, made it perfectly clear where I was going wrong.  In the end I ended up having a separate service in my swarm for nginx.

Comment: Correct, if you use swarm the approach with separate service is the right way to do this :)